# Using MvxImageViewLoader to load a resource image, is it possible?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using mvvmcross binding in a MvxTableViewCell, the cell elements are an UIImageView and 2 labels.

These "rows"/cells will list a set of predefined elements, the image of these elements are png files that exist inside the Resources directory (bundle resource) or at any place on the internet.

Since I might have this mix of images that exist in the bundle and on the internet I would like to use MvxImageViewLoader.

The view model has a list of objects that contain a property that is the image uri, for the resource images I tried several solutions: 
- NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath+"/xpto.png" 
- "file://" + NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath+"/xpto.png"

All the images that are located in the internet work without any problem.

Is it possible to use MvxImageViewLoader to load images that exist in the resource folder? Should I use a converter?

Thanks for your help,

Luis Pinho

Comment: Where is your code ? Show us your existing codes please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MvvmCross DownloadCache plugin on Touch resolves image loading to: MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch/MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader.cs

This uses `res:` as the scheme/prefix to detect whether a resource file has been requestd and then uses `UIImage.FromFile` to load them.

Since other platforms do not support resource files using the same prefix, you may find you need to use a value converter for this when moving to multiple platforms.

Alternatively, you could easily implement your own `MyImageView` control inheriting from `MvxImageView` which would intercept the bound property and decide whether to download it or to display it from resources.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, using res: worked fine, I'll build a converter for the Android

Comment: MvvmCross now supports using "res:" for Android too: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/commit/49382ab1fe6daa4012560a8af8a0c0bb4efe8fab