# MVVMCross IOS assets binding to cell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, ffimageloading

I have a table data and images to assets folder.
I need to bind image by name from assets to TableCell
How can I do it?

I've found old solutions for MVVMCross.Binding 5.7.0 with MvxImageViewLoader, but when I added it to solutions I got references duplicate. 
I realized that I can use converter for that, but I want to try avoid converter usage.
Also I can use ffimageloading package, but I didn't find any solution for it.

Comment: Here is a similar case ,maybe it is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462371/using-mvximageviewloader-to-load-a-resource-image-is-it-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more simple that I've thought. 
Only 3 steps:

**The first one:**

set custom class for UIImageView
[image]

**The second one:**

Create an outlet for UIImageView. Pay attention to type.
[image]

And
**The third one:**
bind URL

[image]

Answer (score -1):

have you tried that in your cell?

```
_imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => ImageView)
{
    DefaultImagePath = "res:" + NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(imageName, "png")
};
```

Comment: Have u read my question? 
I wrote that `MvxImageViewLoader` removed since version 6.